# Does it make sense to stress test a cloud system that can autoscale?

Tags: stress-testing, k6

From k6 https://k6.io/docs/test-types/stress-testing/

It says that a stress test is used to check a system's capacity by pushing it to the breaking point. The article has an example to test for scaling up and down but the graph does not show any failed requests.

My question is, if the system can scale up in the cloud indefinitely, then it seems it does not have a breaking point, so in this case is it really a stress test? Would it be more appropriate to call that a scalability test? Or are the two basically the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

It may be useful to test your cloud configuration. For example one may use ASG in AWS to scale EC2s up. But their configuration could be not good enough. Let's say you scale up when average CPU usage is more than %80 some problems may occur:

- CPU is not the actual bottleneck; database, network, storage, RAM could be a bottleneck too
- New applications can't start fast enough (DB connection may slow because lots of request or you have lots of service and it needs to ping/health check them etc) and your remaining EC2s will be under heavy pressure.